# Poner whidth y height al mismo tamaño en porcentaje

Tags: html, css, scss

Necesito que cuando se modifique el `width` de un div, el `height:` adquiera el mismo tamaño. En otras palabras que el div siempre se vea cuadrado cuando se cambie el tamaño de la pagina. ¿Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Hola, depende del caso, ¿quiere que se aplique al iniciar la pagina o hay algún evento que hace que el width se modifique?

Comment: no solo que si el div obtiene el 50% de la pagina, el height obtenga el valor, que se vea un cuadrado

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es utilizar porcentajes en el height puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Así ya puedes usar:

> **height: 50% En el contenedor que quieres dimensionar**

Para determinar el height de un div dentro de otro div, debes especificar el height del div padre en 100% parecido a como lo vez arriba, y luego el otro div ocupará el tanto por ciento del height del padre.

Hay otra forma, usando la unidad vh o vw, que significan

**vh**: Tanto por ciento de la altura del viewport.
**vw**: Lo mismo pero para el ancho.

en ese caso, lo colocarías

```
.contenedor{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
}
```

Lo bueno es que esta opción no te limita el height del body y del html a 100%, sino que lo usas directo en el contenedor.

> Pero ojo con la compatibilidad en los navegadores...

Todo es cuestión de experimentar... Suerte!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar la misma unidad de medida en el alto y el ancho del witdh, y deberias usar vw (porcentaje del ancho del viewport). La pega es que si lo tienes todo en un contenedor con un limite de ancho, tipo max-width:800px, el div seguira creciendo cuando amplies el navegador porque toma la medida de la ventana, no de su contenedor. 
Para evitarlo, tendrías que ponerle un media query que lo bloquee a partir de esa medida..

Si tienes 10 divs, para evitar tener que ponerle un media query a cada uno, puedes usar ems como unidad de medida haciendo algo así:

```
body{font-size:6vw;}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
body {font-size:48px}
}

div{
width:3em;
height:3em;
}
```